# how to send a single command via docker attach and exit with crtl+p and crtl+q

Tags: docker

How can I do the following via script?

- run the command: docker attach my_container
- enter to the existing TTY: enable backup
- detach again with crtl+p ctrl+q

Answer (score 1):

Just do `docker exec`:

```
docker exec my_container echo "hello, world!"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

Comment: I have also tried this, but it does not work. Your command starts the echo process and do not send "hello, world!" to stdin of the detached docker process.

Comment: @Wookiee Sorry, might have missed that point. If you know the PID of the process, you can direct echo to the input stream: `echo 'smth' > /proc/<pid>/fd/0`